# HTML & CSS Unordered list doesn't stay in its containing DIV

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a div with an unordered list in it. When I render it (see pictures attached), it seems that the unordered list doesn't stay within its DIV, it stays beneath the DIV.

I've already searched for answers on google but i can't manage to find one.

Here's how the site looks: 
[image]

```css
h1 {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 color: #09AA34;
}
p1 {
 font-size: 200px;
}
.header {
 width: 900px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 200px; 
}
.navigation {
 background-color: #c6e2ff ;
 background-image: url("ocean.jpg");
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: thin;
}
.navigation ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-bottom: 0; 
}
.navigation li {
 color:  #ffffff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Raleway', bold;
 padding: 25px 100px;
 font-weight: uppercase;
 text-align: left;
}
.NavigationWords{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 195px;
 float: left;
}
h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 background-color: #c6e2ff;
 color:  #ffffff;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url("ocean.jpg");
}
p {
 margin-top: 0;
 font-family: 'Raleway', bold;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.Join {
 margin-top: 0; 
}
.Portfolio {
}
.Future {
}
.LeftPanel {
 border-style: solid;
 max-width: 180px;
 max-height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
}
.LeftPanel ul {
 list-style-type: none; 
}
.LeftPanel li {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Belgian Entertainment</title>
  <link href="belgian.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,700|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="header"> Belgian Entertainment </h1>

  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li> ABOUT </li>
      <li> JOIN </li>
      <li> PORTFOLIO </li>
      <li> FUTURE </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="NavigationWords">
    <div class="About">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p> text
      <br/>
      <br/>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Join">
      <h2>Join</h2>
      <p> text
      <br/>
      <br/>
       </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Portfolio">
      <h2> Portfolio </h2>
      <p> text.
      <a href="www.imgur.com"> BE Portfolio </a>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Future">
      <h2> Future </h2>
      <p> text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="LeftPanel">
    <ul>
      <li>Login</li>
      <li>Sign-up</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a closing `</div>` tag after the list?

Comment: Yes, i have a closing div.

Comment: Well you have now I made a snippet for you :)

Comment: I think it may be caused with how you are positioning the `LeftPanel` using CSS. Can you show us how you are positioning this panel beside the main content?

Comment: i included the whole code in the post

Comment: i think you want LeftPanel div left side of the Navigation right? for that you need to positioning the LeftPanel

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you don't have a closing `</div>` at the end, it's bugging out.

If you do have the closing div in your code, are your styles inheriting more styles from some parent element? Could you include all the code for the page?

```css
.LeftPanel {
  border-style: solid;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.LeftPanel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.LeftPanel li {}
```

```html
<div class="LeftPanel">
  <ul>
    <li>Login</li>
    <li>Sign-up</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>MORE</li>
    <li>MORE</li>
    <li>MORE</li>
    <li>MORE</li>
    <li>MORE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for a PEN - just hit the `<>` snippet editor as I did

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` to LeftPanel div and wrapping `NavigationWords` and `LeftPanel` div with parent div with `position:relative`

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #09AA34;
}
p1 {
  font-size: 200px;
}
.header {
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
.navigation {
  background-color: #c6e2ff ;
  background-image: url("ocean.jpg");
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navigation li {
  color:  #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway', bold;
  padding: 25px 100px;
  font-weight: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
}
.NavigationWords{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 195px;
  float: left;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: #c6e2ff;
  color:  #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("ocean.jpg");
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', bold;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.Join {
  margin-top: 0; 
}
.Portfolio {
}
.Future {
}
.LeftPanel {
  border-style: solid;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:195px;
  min-height:500px;
}
.LeftPanel ul {
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding:0;
}
.LeftPanel li {
}
.wrap {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Belgian Entertainment</title>
<link href="belgian.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,700|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="header"> Belgian Entertainment </h1>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li> ABOUT </li>
      <li> JOIN </li>
      <li> PORTFOLIO </li>
      <li> FUTURE </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="NavigationWords">
      <div class="About">
        <h2>About</h2>
          <p> text
          <br/>
          <br/>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div class="Join">
        <h2>Join</h2>
          <p> text
          <br/>
          <br/>
           </p>
      </div>

      <div class="Portfolio">
        <h2> Portfolio </h2>
        <p> text.
        <a href="www.imgur.com"> BE Portfolio </a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="Future">
        <h2> Future </h2>
        <p> text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="LeftPanel">
      <ul>
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>Sign-up</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```